# Which one is more expensive with socket.io: sending messages to rooms or to socket ids?

Tags: websocket, socket.io

Think of a mobile app which a user can install to multiple devices and use the same user account on all of them. Each device should receive the same notifications. You are going to implement this notification system with socket.io.

Which of the following approaches is more expensive in terms of memory and cpu usage?

**Approach-1:** Each device of the user joins a room called say "u:N" where N is user's id. You send messages to room "u:N".

**Approach-2:** You save the ids of the sockets of the user to a database such as Redis and send the messages to each socket by retrieving socket ids and emitting to those.